# After using scrollTo(int x, int y) method in ListView, I scrolled down and it went to top again

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scroll

I want to use the method `scrollTo(int x, int y)` to let my `ListView` to local the point (x,y), but after the method working, I scrolled down the `ListView`, the scroller bar went back to the top again. I don't know why. The method `smoothScrollBy(distance, duration)` works, but can't satisfy me. By the way, every item's height in my `ListView` is over the screen's.

p.s: I am Chinese, I am so crazy about English, but it might make you confuse.